# Hey i want to build my own php encoder, can you point me to some tutorials?

Tags: php, encryption, base64

I tried using mycrypt with key and base64 to encrypt and then decode the code, but the code is in a variable so when i output this using eval, i am always getting errors so could you point me in the right direction, I also looked at building my own php extension but i wouldn't know how to output it into working php code.

### UPDATE

I have got it to work, now I am going to convert it into an extension, I am just wondering can people decompile php extensions?

Comment: Please provide your example code with errors that come up.

Comment: bas64 isn't encryption, it's just an encoding method. Much like your groceries aren't a Chevy, just because you went to the store in a Chevy. And FYI, `eval()` is evil. Do NOT use it. Ever.

Comment: I encrypt using mcrypt and then use base64 to encode because i cannot paste the mycrypt encoding.

Comment: You should post what you did

Comment: Maybe in this special case a none open-source software fits better to your needs - take a look at e.g. [www.codecanyon.net](https://codecanyon.net/search/php%20encoder) and search for `php encoder` and you can take a look how they did it ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"can people decompile php extensions?"

Yes, it's certainly possible to reverse engineer and/or decompile compiled C code back to pseudo-code or source, but with your approach no one is going to need to in order to expose the code that you believe that you are protecting as in reality it is merely hidden.

The eval() function that you are calling is part of the opensource PHP core, and the source code could be trivially exposed either by modifying the eval() module function or the function referenced by the zend_compile_string function pointer (typically this is the address of the compile_string function).

Systems such as Zend and ionCube operate on compiled code (which PHP always produces ready for execution), and it's the bytecode that is encoded. Consequently there is no source code in encoded files to be restored at runtime. Additionally, a required component on the server may also contain a closed source execution engine rather than passing restored bytecode to the default bytecode execution engine in the PHP core, keeping bytecode more hidden and giving the opportunity to execute bytecode that does not conform to the usual PHP bytecode structure (hence needing more reverse engineering effort to understand it).

Answer (score 2):

Why would you want to write your own encoder? Please, don't. The problem is that, at some point you **will** need to decode it into plain PHP code to feed to the PHP interpreter. And at that point someone can just come it and dump the code to a file.

Professional solutions like [Zend_Guard](http://www.zend.com/en/products/guard/) and [ionCube](http://www.ioncube.com/) are the only solutions that actually work and are not hackable in 15 minutes by anyone with minimal PHP knowledge.

Comment: Well what I am currently doing is using eval in the function with no return so the code is executed without being returned on the php, so if I make this into an extension that cant be decompiled, then i think it should be quite secure, would they be able to dump it like that?. If this is not possible how do professional encoders like ioncube and phpshield do it? and there are a lot of website online that offer dezending hence why I wanted to make my own encoder.

Comment: Most Dezenders don't work but are scams. That said, anything can be broken, with enough determination. Here's an [official response on Zend Guard](http://forums.zend.com/viewtopic.php?f=57&t=2242). The best protection you can give your sourcecode is legal, however. Like a contract or a EULA.